# Android activity with different logcat package than the rest

Tags: android, android-activity, logcat

My app has an ActivityLifecycleCallback registered. All it does is keep a static counter of how many outstanding activities there are and writes to logcat as the number increases and decreases. It allows the app to know when an activity closes if it was because another activity in the app opened or if it was because the app was backgrounded.

This works great for all the activities except one. This one activity keeps a separate counter and logs differently in logcat. The entries in logcat for this activity only have the activity name, not the full package path.

All the activities are in the same package, and they are all launched the same way. What could cause this one to go rouge like this? Below is a sample from logcat showing the two different types of log entries.

```
11-08 23:27:33.606  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity resumed: 2
11-08 23:27:34.016  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity stopped: 1
11-08 23:27:38.621  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity resumed: 2
11-08 23:27:39.362  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity stopped: 1
11-08 23:27:41.745  24390-24390/.YourHealth W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity resumed: 1
11-08 23:27:42.105  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity stopped: 0
11-08 23:27:46.890  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity resumed: 1
11-08 23:27:47.301  24390-24390/.YourHealth W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity stopped: 0
11-08 23:27:50.884  24390-24390/.YourHealth W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity resumed: 1
11-08 23:27:51.285  20362-20362/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest W/LifecycleHandler﹕ Activity stopped: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be because in my AndroidManifes.xml file I had defined the `android:process` attribute for those specific activities.

Removing it gave them the standard process name in the logcat and caused them to also be handled properly by the ActivityLifecycleCallback.